# Receive all values within a day & create average

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a **date**(type:DateTime) column and a **price**(type:Decimal) column within my db. Records are created and saved hourly.  I need to create a rake task to go through all of my stored data and create an average price for each day.

Using ActiveRecord, how can I query all of my records, group together all records within each day, create a new average price from those 24 records, and save it as a new record in a different table?

I imagine it would be something like this psuedocode:

```
Sales.all
  loop through them and group records by day
    loop through each grouping and create average
      average = DailyAverage.create
```

FYI I have about 10,000 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope is nice way to select some records and group them. In Sales class define something like `scope :by_date, ->(needful_date) { where{ date == needful_date} }`. Then in another model(which relates to another table) define your calculations:

```
def calculate_average_prices
  first_sale_date = # find your first sale date
  date_range = first_sale_date..Date.today
  grouped_sales = date_range.map{|date| Sales.by_date(date)}
  average_prices = grouped_sales.map do |sales|
    sales.map{|sale| sale.price.to_f}.average
  end
  # save your average prices
end
```

It's just an idea of solution. You'd better understand it and implement yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I have about 3,650 days that need to be grouped.  Can I enter in a date range into the needful_date param in the scope?

Comment: If you want to use `by_date` with range, that's ok. Just update `by_date` with something like `->(date_range) { where{ date_range.include?(date)} }`